# Расположение кода программы в памяти компьютера

Tags: windows, memory

Прочитал, что программы скомпилированные на VS имеют базовый адрес в памяти 0x00400000. Стало интересно как в памяти буду располагаться 2 программы. Написал, запустил и обе пишут адрес  0x00400000, но как? почему две разные программы располагаются по 1 адресу? разве такое возможно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это виртуальная память, которая у каждого процесса своя. В итоге, два процесса могут быть загружены по виртуальному адресу 0x400000 и не мешать друг-другу.
Есть физическая память, допустим 4 гига - от 0x00000000 до 0xFFFFFFFF. Ядро операционной системы выделяет, например, физический кусок 0x70000000 - 0x80000000 для процесса. И изнутри процесс видит эту память как 0x400000 - 0x10400000. Для второго процесса выделается 0x8000000-0x90000000, а изнутри он видит те же адреса, что и первый.

Comment: а как допустим узнать его реальное, а не виртуальное расположение в памяти? и как вообще понять "виртуальная память"?

Comment: Есть физическая память, допустим 4 гига - от 0x00000000 до 0xFFFFFFFF. Ядро операционной системы выделяет, например, физический кусок 0x70000000 - 0x80000000 для процесса. И изнутри процесс видит эту память как 0x400000 - 0x10400000. Для второго процесса выделается 0x8000000-0x90000000, а изнутри он видит те же адреса. Зачем вам, кстати, физические адреса?

Comment: спасибо большое. понял, принял, разобрался)

Comment: @WenSiL дальше надо читать Таненбаума и/или Русиновича, а заодно Интеловскую документацию на кристаллы.

Comment: «Реальное» положение не имеет особого смысла для программиста. Например, страница виртуальной памяти может быть вытеснена на диск, и потом загружена по другим физическим адресам.